# Написать программу, которая находит количество символов в верхнем регистре в заданной строке

Tags: python

я 0 в питоне умоляю помогите

есть пример похожей задачи но там ошибка

```
input_string = input ("Введите текст: ")
for char in input string:
    if char. isdigit():
         digits_count += 1 
    elif char.ispunct () :
         punctuations_count += 1
print ("Количество цифр в строке: digits_count")
print ("Количество знаков препинания в строке: punctuations_count")
```

Comment: `for char in input string:` - должно быть подчеркивание между input и string, т.к. это имя переменной, объявленной в строке выше.

Comment: да там он был, забыл внести, но и без этого ошибка, она в count_digits, не находит его

Comment: Ну добавьте в начало digits_count = 0 и punctuations_count = 0. Не находит, потому что их нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, в одну строку и вообще без переменных:

```py
print(f'Количество букв в верхнем регистре: {sum(map(str.isupper, input("Введите текст: ")))}')
```

Но лучше учитесь писать всё же сами.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант функции, котороя посчитает количество букв в верхнем регистре:

```
def up_let():
    line = str(input('Введите текст: '))
    count = 0
    for letter in line:
        if letter.isupper():
            count += 1
    return ('Букв в верхнем регистре: {}'.format(count))

up_let()
```

Comment: 1) преобразование в `str` излишне, `input` и так строковый 2) `.format` уже не модно использовать, когда есть `f-строки` )

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, я просто редко работаю со строками, поэтому не все помню) На будущее учту)